# jQuery Selector Bug with <object> element in IE 6 & 7? Or did I miss something

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Found a really weird problem with jQuery in IE7 today where it isn't finding  selectors properly inside an  element. Here's the HTML code:

```
<DIV id=firstVideoWrap>
    <OBJECT style="FLOAT: left" id=firstVideo width=300 height=300>
        <PARAM NAME="allowfullscreen" VALUE="true" />
        <PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="http://vimeo.com/">
    </OBJECT>
</DIV>
<DIV id=secondVideoWrap>
    <OBJECT style="FLOAT: left" id=secondVideo width=300 height=300>
        <PARAM NAME="allowscriptaccess" VALUE="always" />
        <PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE=http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf />
        <PARAM NAME="wmode" VALUE="opaque" />
    </OBJECT>
</DIV>
```

and the relevant javascript:

```
console.log(jQuery("#firstVideo param").length);
console.log(jQuery("#firstVideoWrap param").length);
console.log(jQuery("#secondVideo param").length);
console.log(jQuery("#secondVideoWrap param").length);
```

It is giving the output:

```
5
2
5
3
```

Here it is in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uGpUy/2/

It seems that IE isn't counting the number of param's on an object and instead is counting all param's on the entire page. While when I use the wrapping div it counts them correctly.

Also If I do:

```
jQuery("#secondVideo > param").length
```

It works correctly.

Is this a jQuery bug or something I've done wrong in my code?

EDIT: I've submitted a jQuery bug ticket for this: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11646, will see how that progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be a bug related to the `<OBJECT />` tag.  If you replace your `<OBJECT />` tags with `<DIV />` tags, [it works just as you intended](http://jsfiddle.net/uGpUy/8/):

```
2
2
3
3
```

---

[I did get it to work](http://jsfiddle.net/uGpUy/7/) by using [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) on the `<OBJECT />` selectors:

```
console.log(jQuery("#firstVideo").children("param").length);
console.log(jQuery("#firstVideoWrap param").length);
console.log(jQuery("#secondVideo").children("param").length);
console.log(jQuery("#secondVideoWrap param").length);
```

**Outputs:**

```
2
2
3
3
```

---

**Another Note:**

The bug seems to be in the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method, as [when I tried to use that](http://jsfiddle.net/uGpUy/10/) instead of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) it returned:

```
5
2
5
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more, in IE8 all four lengths are 0. Using `jQuery("#secondVideo > param")` also yields 0... No idea why it happens.